# React Native create class with key-value pair props

Tags: javascript, react-native, class, constructor, react-props

```
class Adder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.callback(this.props.valueA + this.props.valueB)
  }
}
```

In JSX I can do this:

```
<Adder callback={this.resultFunc} valueA={4} valueB={2}/>
```

I don't know the syntax in JS, for instance this doesn't work. I only get the first argument passed:

```
this.myAdder = new Adder({callback:this.resultFunc},{valueA:4},{valueB:2});
```

Anything but the first KV pair is undefined in the Adder class.
Can anyone please point me right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put them all in the same object:

```
this.myAdder = new Adder({callback: this.resultFunc, valueA: 4, valueB: 2});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the Adder takes only one argument but you are passing three
the props is a single object

```
this.myAdder = new Adder({callback:this.resultFunc,valueA:4,valueB:2});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one object: new Adder({callback:this.resultFunc, valueA:4, valueB:2}) this will be your props.